# Redirect component doesn't change url (React)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router

I am building `Signup` component which should redirect to the root path if user has passed all information.

However, Redirect component doesn't work for some reason, as url is not changed. On `line 12` I am logging `in renderRedirect` and I can see this message in my console so I am inside `renderRedirect` method but, like I said, url stays the same `localhost:3000/signup`m instead of changing to `localhost:3000/`.

Any idea why?

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Signup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    password: "",
    fullName: "",
    email: ""
  };

  renderRedirect = () => {
    console.log("in renderRedirect");
    return <Redirect push to="/" />;
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
  handleSignup = () => {
    this.props.onSignup(
      {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        fullName: this.state.fullName,
        email: this.state.email
      },
      () => this.renderRedirect()
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-wrap">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>

        <div className="form">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Full Name"
            name="fullName"
            value={this.state.fullName}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSignup}>Sign up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Is the parent component supposed to be rendering the second param passed to `onSignup`? A `render` method somewhere must be returning this `<Redirect />` for it to do the work you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I would omit the 'push' from the redirect component and see if that works. Otherwise, you could make use of the history object and use this.props.history.push('/') instead. If you don't have access to the routeProps, you can wrap your Signup Component with { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'